# Reference a second data set in spss?

Tags: python, spss

I have one table with IDs and rows of data that happened in different time points. Some IDs don't have all the timepoints because they either haven't happened yet, or the person was not eligible to continue. I need to create new rows for each ID and to fill them in with an error code.

I have a second data table containing the IDs with the error codes I would like to use.

My goal is: to append new rows to my first table filled in with the error codes specified in the second table.

How can I use syntax to avoid manually creating new rows an filling in the information based off a second table in SPSS?

for example:

Table A

| ID | timepoint | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 12 | 13 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 | 22 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 11 | 11 | 45 |
| 2 | 1 | 81 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | 32 | 21 |
| 3 | 1 | 11 | 15 | 12 |

Table B: Why missing?

| ID | timepoint | whyMissing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | -20 |
| 3 | 2 | -15 |
| 3 | 3 | -15 |

Desired Table C:

| ID | timepoint | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 12 | 13 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 | 22 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 11 | 11 | 45 |
| 2 | 1 | 81 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | 32 | 21 |
| 2 | 3 | -20 | -20 | -20 |
| 3 | 1 | 11 | 15 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | -15 | -15 | -15 |
| 3 | 3 | -15 | -15 | -15 |

```
SORT CASES BY SubjectID AssessmentPeriod.

* Match TableCBase with TableB to identify missing combinations.
MATCH FILES /FILE=*
  /TABLE=TableB
  /BY ID timepoint.

* Create new rows in TableCBase for missing combinations with specific error codes.
IF $CASENUM = 0.
  DO REPEAT #i = value1 value2 value3 / #r = whyMissing whyMissing whyMissing.
    COMPUTE #i = #r.
  END REPEAT.
  DATASET NAME TableBError.
END IF.

* Combine the modified TableCBase with TableA.
MATCH FILES /FILE=*
  /TABLE=TableCBase
  /BY ID timepoint.

* Sort the final table.
SORT CASES BY ID timepoint.
```

I have tried this syntax but I can't seem to get this to even import correctly into my existing syntax.

If I could use python to do this, this is what I would use:

```
# Update the data columns with missing data codes
data_columns = [f'Value{i}' for i in range(1, 5)]  # Adjust based on the actual number of columns

# Get all unique subject IDs and assessment periods from Table A
all_subjects = table_a['subjectID'].unique()
all_periods = table_a['AssessmentPeriod'].unique()

# Create a master dataframe with all combinations of subject IDs and assessment periods
master_df = pd.DataFrame([(subject, period) for subject in all_subjects for period in all_periods],
                         columns=['subjectID', 'AssessmentPeriod'])

# Merge with Table B to get missing data codes
table_c_base = pd.merge(master_df, table_b, on=['subjectID', 'AssessmentPeriod'], how='left', suffixes=('_B', ''))

# Merge with Table A to get corresponding data values
table_c_base = pd.merge(table_c_base, table_a, on=['subjectID', 'AssessmentPeriod'], how='left', suffixes=('_B', '_A'))

#fill NA
table_c_base['Value1']=table_c_base['value1'].fillna(table_c_base['whyMissing'])
table_c_base['Value2']=table_c_base['Value2'].fillna(table_c_base['whyMissing'])
table_c_base['Value3']=table_c_base['Value3'].fillna(table_c_base['whyMissing'])


table_c_base= table_c_base.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, the better strategy is to `add files` instead of `match files`. Like this:

```
dataset activate TableCBase.
add files /file=* /file=TableB.
do repeat vr=var1 to var3.
   if missing(vr) vr=whyMissing.
end repeat.
```

The syntax adds the additional data as new rows to begin with, and then copies the error codes into the empty variables.

Comment: Thank you for your response! With this solution, I run into some issues with using it with my syntax. Does TableCBase have to already exist and have to be imported into the syntax? When I try to run this, I get errors that say it is empty, which is frustrating because I need it to be empty in order to add things to it!

I am starting with GET FILE= for path to table A
and GET FILE= for path to table B.

Comment: After getting each file use `dataset name .....". Then the syntax refers to the datasets using their name - both in `dataset activate .... ` and `match files /file= .... `

Comment: Thank you that helped a great deal. What I have up to this point, are both datasets activated and have used the MATCH FILES so that I now have a database that contains the whyMissing values if applicable. 
When I try to use this, I cannot get this to repeat for the life of me! 
I have even tried to replace one variable at a time with whyMissing if there is a missing value. I have used 
IF MISSING (var1) var1=whyMissing
EXECUTE.
I do not seem to understand why none of the missing values will update. I would greatly appreciate your help, even if it is for one variable at a time!

Comment: I have also tried modifying the code to this: 
VECTOR Value= Value1 TO Value10. 

DO REPEAT Value = Value2 /why = whyMissing.
  IF (MISSING(Value)) Value = why.
END REPEAT.

It runs, but it does not update my column/columns.

Comment: If you use `match files` the way you did in your original post, you will not get any values in `whymissing` var, because there are no matches. That's why I suggested you use `add files` instead. I edited my code to work in the same direction you are trying above. Note - for `do repeat` you don't need `vector`, you don't need to repeat the constant (whyMissing), and you can't include `execute` within a  command - just put one at the end of the process - as a separate command.